# Insert rows based on values pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, insert, append, rows

I have this:

[image]

I would like to achieve this using pandas:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like the textbook use case for [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
In [46]: df = pd.read_excel('your_file.xlsx')

In [47]: df
Out[47]:
         position title  ccs  alc  hs
0          loader    mr    1  NaN   2
1  something else   mrs    2  3.0   4

In [48]: df.set_index(['position', 'title']).stack()
Out[48]:
position        title
loader          mr     ccs    1.0
                       hs     2.0
something else  mrs    ccs    2.0
                       alc    3.0
                       hs     4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be unsure about about what you want, but I believe you are trying to add rows of one data frame to another data frame:

[Use pd.concat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)